# What are the steps to upgrade Spring XD using the Ambari Plugin?

Tags: spring-xd, ambari

I successfully installed Spring XD 1.2.0 RC1 on HDP 2.2 using the Ambari plugin.  Now that Spring XD 1.2.0 GA is out, how do I go about upgrading my installation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to remove the RC1 install and replace it with the 1.2.0 GA. I didn't see an option for updating a service in the Ambari UI.

These are the steps I took:

1) stop the Spring XD service from Amabari UI

2) remove old Spring XD plugin:

```
yum remove springxd-plugin-hdp
```

3) remove Spring XD installation:

```
yum remove spring-xd
rm -Rf /opt/pivotal/spring-xd-1.2.0.RC1
```

4) remove YUM repo and symbolic link:

```
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/SPRINGXD-1.2-1.repo
rm /var/www/html/SPRINGXD-1.2-1
```

5) get and install new YUM repo:

```
wget -nv http://repo.spring.io/yum-release/spring-xd/1.2/spring-xd-1.2.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/spring-xd-1.2.repo
```

6) install new Spring XD plugin:

```
yum install spring-xd-plugin-hdp
```

7) Restart Ambari server:

```
ambari-server restart
```

8) Delete old Spring XD service (adjust the ambari-server-host and cluster names):

```
curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X DELETE  http://<ambari-server-host>:8080/api/v1/clusters/<cluster>/services/SPRINGXD
```

(refresh the browser for Ambari UI)

9) Check the repository link under Admin->Repositories. It should be:

```
redhat6    Spring-XD-1.2    http://repo.spring.io/yum-release/spring-xd/1.2
```

10) Install new Spring XD Service following this doc: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-ambari/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/InstallingXDwithAmbari.asciidoc

Let us know if this works for you or if you have any issues.