# Upgrade SCDF on YARN with Ambari

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I started using SCDF from `spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn 1.0.2.RELEASE`. It was installed via `Ambari 2.4.2` and is now running along with `HDP2.5`(Hortonworks Data Platform).

Now,a lot has changed in SCDF, so I want to upgrade spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn from 1.0.2 to 1.1.1(or 1.2.* when there is a release version).

At first, I followed [Deploying on AMBARI](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/yarn-deploying-on-ambari.html) section and installed `scdf-plugin-hdp` from `scdf-release-1.1.1.repo`. After restart Ambari, there is no option for the upgrading. So, I think this is not the right way.

However, I searched a lot and did not find a guide for SCDF Upgrading.

What should I do for a safe SCDF upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately due to limitations in ambari there is no upgrade support and you need to do a new cluster installation. We are a custom service which ambari cannot upgrade. We'll add upgrade support when ambari adds possibility to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Janne. Since there are other services running in the cluster, it is almost impossible to reinstall the whole cluster only for SCDF upgrade. I searched with keyword "update Ambari plugin" and found a similar question [What are the steps to upgrade Spring XD using the Ambari Plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004677/what-are-the-steps-to-upgrade-spring-xd-using-the-ambari-plugin). Hope I have the luck to find a workaround.

Comment: In theory it might work if you remove all SCDF services, stop server, uninstall old plugin, install new plugin and then start to add services back. This approach is very brittle and never really tested. Idea behind this is that you can install SCDF to existing ambari cluster but it's a little unknown if ambari fully removes all traces when services are deleted.